# disallow direct access to nginx location

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have two locations in nginx, where one redirect to another. I want to make next:

First one allow direct access in browser and redirect query to second location. Second location transform get to post, make proxy query and allowed only from first location.

First:

```
location /first/ {
         rewrite ^ /second/ permanent;
}
```

Second:

```
location /second/ {

proxy_method POST;
proxy_set_body '{ "arg1": "$arg_arg1", "arg2": "$arg_arg2" }
proxy_pass https://some_api.com/

}
```

How could I check in second location if it redirected from first one (not direct access in browser) and show some 40x error if it was direct access?

Trying to use `internal` directive, but this rewrite does not fall into the category of internal redirects.

Redirect using to hide /first/ url in user browser

Thanx in advance

Comment: You almost made it yourself, yet should read the `rewrite` directive documentation more carefully. `permanent` and `redirect` flags finish request processing by generating HTTP 301/302 redirects, `last` and `break` ones control the request processing flow. Use `rewrite ^ /second/ last;` in the first location block, `internal` in the second one. The trailing slash after `some_api.com` will be assumed as an URI to pass, `proxy_pass https://some_api.com;` without the trailing slash will pass the current request URI (already rewritten to `/second/`).

Comment: Wait, maybe I didn't understand your question, but you can have either 301/302 redirect (new request issued from the user browser, an URL in the browser address bar get changed) or internal rewrite (no additional requests, URL does not get changed). It should be obvious that making the second location protected from the direct access with `internal` keyword will limit your choices only to the second one (no redirection, internal rewrite only).

Comment: Ivan, thanks for reply. When I use ```rewrite ^ /second/ last;``` in first location  and  ```proxy_pass https://some_api.com;``` (without the trailing slash) it rewrites url to ```/second/``` but show 404 error (dont pass ```internal```). If I use with trailing slash ```proxy_pass https://some_api.com/;```  it leaves ```/first/``` url and make query to proxy (pass throw ```internal``` normally), but I need rewrite to ```/second``` and pass throw ```internal```.

Comment: So, when it rewrites internally it doesnt make new request and first url is not hidden. Thats why I ask, maybe any other mechanism in nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about nginx, rather about HTTP protocol and user browser behavior. Whatever you are trying to do, I think you are trying to do it in a wrong way. Generally, you need to generate some one-time token at your first location and use it at the second one, but this is a web app job, nginx is just a web server and not a web framework (however it can be possible using third party modules like [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module)). If you want to do it using nginx itself, no matter what solution you'll finished up with, it will be possible to trace and spoof it.

Here is an idea in general:

```
location /first/ {
    # set cookie with an access token
    add_header Set-Cookie "my_token=my_super_password; path=/second/" always;
    # do not use 301 redirect here or it will be cached by user browser, use 302 only!
    rewrite ^ /second/ redirect;
}
location /second/ {
    if ($cookie_my_token != "my_super_password") { return 403; }
    # clear the token cookie on response
    add_header Set-Cookie "my_token=deleted; path=/second/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" always;
    ... rest of configuration here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention and advice, Ivan. This is a working solution. Agree with you, this is a job for a web application rather than web server.

Comment: If you found the solution workable, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) the answer (while it isn't obligatorily, it can help other people to see the solution was checked and accepted).